# Serverside user-identification

Tags: php, android, google-api, google-api-php-client

So this might gonna be a newbe question.

I'm developing an REST(ful) JSON application programming interface with PHP. This API will be primarily accessed by Android-devices via an App. Due to the fact only people with G+ Accounts will use this app I want to use Google API for user-authentication. So far, so simple.

But I'm using GoogleAPI for the first time and I read interesting and needed parts of the Google API DevDocs. So I found the **google-api-php-client** that I'm using for now.

Here is how I thought this auth-process works:

1. User logs into G+Account on mobile device (or similar; I read something about an PlayStore ID Token or something [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html))
2. The app does have a token now (like stated [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) (response)) 
   `"access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
   "expires_in":3920,
   "token_type":"Bearer"`
3. Android-App sends Request to my PHP API like `GET /meeting/:id` and sends  the access_token (`1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg` only), too.
4. My app can take the access_token and can ask `googleAPI/people/me` for the ID of the user.
5. User is identified in request on my API and the magic can go on

But there is a problem with the mentioned Google-lib for PHP:
the function `setAccessToken($accessToken)` requires **the whole JSON-response** as the docs says:

`{"access_token":"TOKEN", 
"refresh_token":"TOKEN", 
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600, 
"id_token":"TOKEN", 
"created":1320790426}`

(see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/Google_Client.php?r=474)) of a auth-request to GoogleAPI.

It can't be the solution to send the whole JSON-response with id_token, refresh_token and access_token to my API on every request as this will cause huge load of traffic and I'm sure that there is a simple solution, but I don't see it.

I hope I could explain my thoughts and problems properly and I hope that my english is not that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this.

The id_token is enough to identify the User. When the android app sends a request with the id_token in it the server can ask google for its identity.

In **google-api-php-client** this works with:

`$id_token = $_GET['id_token'];
$client = new Google_Client();
$attr = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token)->getAttributes();
echo $attr['payload']['sub'];`

I found this in [Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth?hl=de) (there's also a "Recommended flow"-description) and with help of one of the [mentioned link](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) in the question.